# ¿Cómo insertar intervalos de fechas en mi base de datos con las funciones de Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Hola necesito insertar en mi base de datos dos fechas, fecha_inicio y fecha_fin, la fecha_inicio la tomo de cualquier función que me dé la fecha actual, pero la fecha_fin debe ser la suma del intervalo de la fecha_inicio + 31 días, para eso existe en mysql la función SELECT ADDDATE('2020-10-22', INTERVAL 31 DAY);

Lo que no logro hacer es llevar esa función de mysql a php, y que genere la fecha_fin que necesito y que se pueda guardar en una variable y se inserte en la base de datos, hay muy poca documentación sobre el asunto si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Sé más específico en tu pregunta? eso que ya haces en mysql, lo quieres hacer en PHP?

Comment: Exactamente quiero que me genere en php la fecha actual más 31 días y poder guardar eso en una variable para que se guarde en la base datos.

Comment: Indica lo que has intentando y qué problema o error tienes. Esto se puede hacer tanto desde PHP como en MySQL directamente, dinos desde donde prefieres hacerlo, por qué y con qué código y desde ahí podremos ayudarte mejor. Dinos también de qué tipo es la columna donde quieres guardar el dato.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano gracias por responder, bueno realmente si se puede hacar desde el mismo Mysql está bien, no tengo muy claro como lo harías porque no lo he hecho nunca, ¿tal vez con un trigger?.. Lo que hasta ahora he hecho es algo como esto:                                                                                                 
fecha_inicio = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
fecha_fin = strtotime("+31 day", $fecha_inicio); y el error es que la fecha_fin se almacena en la bd 0000-00-00 el tipo de columna que se desea guardar son dos campos ambos de tipo DATE

Comment: Creo que lo que intentas hacer podría resolverse desde MySQL directamente, pero el problema y el contexto todavía no quedan claros. Si por ejemplo quieres que al insertar un registro se cree una columna con una determinada fecha incrementada en 31 días, eso se puede expresar en la misma instrucción `INSERT` ... Es más, **me preguntaría si realmente hay necesidad de guardar ese dato**... Si es algo que pertenece a la lógica de tu aplicación, podrías calcular el dato *in situ*, cuando lo necesites, en vez de tener un dato durmiendo en tus tablas para, usarlo quién sabe cuando.

Comment: @A.Cedano también he intentado asignarle a una variable la función de Mysql ADDDATE('xxxx-xx-xx', INTERVAL 31 DAY)....... Algo así  
 $fecha_inicio= date(Y-m-d);                             
 $fecha_fin=ADDDATE($fecha_inicio, INTERVAL 31 DAY);

Comment: @A.Cedano Lo que necesito es que en mi tabla se guarde la fecha actual en el campo fecha_inicio y que se guarde la fecha_fin que sería la fecha actual + 31 días

Comment: @A.Cedano necesito la fecha_fin en mi tabla porque es la que le dirá al usuario su fecha de corte de pago y es la que actualizara el estatus de sus publicaciones. Mi proyecto se basa en algo como mercadolibre, publicas un producto pero tienes una fecha limite de publicación y entonces cuando esa fecha limite se cumple tu publicación ya no se muestra.

Comment: Entiendo, pero teniendo la `fecha_inicio` tú puedes calcular *in situ* la *fecha_fin*, por programación, sin necesidad de tener un dato durmiendo y ocupando espacio en la base de datos. No sé si me entiendes a lo que me refiero. Imagina que tienes millones de productos, vas a tener millones de fecha durmiendo sólo por si un día las necesitas. Este tipo de campos es mejor calcularlos en el contexto. De todos modos, si quieres guardarla, muestra el código en que intentas guardarla, para ayudarte. Si lo haces desde PHP es mejor crear ahí al fecha y agregarla a la consulta.

Comment: @A.Cedano ok estoy abierto a hacerlo in situ también, si me explicas como podría trabajarlo así

Comment: @A.Cedano                                                                                            
            $fecha_inicio = date('Y-m-d');
            $fecha_fin = strtotime("+31 day", $fecha_fin);
            $conexion->query("insert into publicacion
            (nombre,caracteristicas,descripcion,precio,inventario,ubicacion,telefono1,
            telefono2,imagen1,fecha_inicio,fecha_fin,id_usuario,id_estado,id_estatus_publicacion,
            id_categoria,id_subcategoria) values
            (

Comment: @A.Cedano '".$_POST['nombre']."',
            '".$_POST['caracteristicas']."',
            '".$_POST['descripcion']."',
            ".$_POST['precio'].",
            ".$_POST['inventario'].",
            '".$_POST['ubicacion']."',
            ".$_POST['telefono1'].",
            ".$_POST['telefono2'].",
            '$nombrefinal',     
            '$fecha',
            '$fecha_fin'
            $id,
            ".$_POST['estado'].",
            '1',
            ".$_POST['categoria'].",
            ".$_POST['subcategoria']."
          )
            ")or die ($conexion->error);

Comment: @A.Cedano Esa es mi consulta para insertar ambas fechas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema concreto aquí, según tu comentario, es un mal uso de `strtotime`. Este es el código que tienes:

```
$fecha_inicio = date('Y-m-d'); 
$fecha_fin = strtotime("+31 day", $fecha_fin);
```

Deberías pasar a `strtotime` el valor de `$fecha_inicio`, algo así:

```
$fecha_fin = strtotime("+31 day", $fecha_inicio);
```

De todos modos, OJO, porque `strtotime` **devuelve una marca del tiempo**, no una fecha formateada. Si tu columna fuese del tipo `TIMESTAMP` la función `strtotime` sería pefecta para obtener el valor e insertarlo, pero como la columna es del tipo `DATE`, tienes que convertir la marca del tiempo que devuelve `strtotime` a un formato de fecha válido que pueda ser reconocido por MySQL al momento de insertar.

Para no liarte demasiado, es mejor trabajar con objetos más específicos. Podríamos pensar en la creación de dos objetos `DateTime` y usar `format` para la inserción y listo.

Aquí te pongo un ejemplo sencillo:

```
#Creamos objeto con la fecha actual
$fecha_inicio = new DateTime(); 
#Creamos objeto con la fecha actual + 31 días
$fecha_fin = new DateTime('now +31 day'); 
#En la instrucción de inserción usamos format para obtner un formato válido para MySQL
$sql="INSERT INTO ... ... VALUES('{$fecha_inicio->format('Ymd')}','{$fecha_fin->format('Ymd')}')";

#Prueba
echo $sql;
```

**Salida:**

```
INSERT INTO ... ... VALUES('20201022','20201122')
```

Vemos aquí que los dos valores obtenidos son: `20201022` y `20201122`. No tienes que preocuparte por formatearlos más, MySQL reconoce perfectamente esos valores como 22 de octubre de 2020 y 22 de noviembre de 2020.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115500/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-como-insertar-intervalos-de-fechas-en-mi-base).

Answer (score 0):

añadir días a una fecha en php es tan sencillo como hacer

```
fecha_inicio = strtotime('2020-02-02')
fecha_fin = strtotime("+31 day", $date)
```

Si quisieras cambiar la fecha, solo tienes que cambiar la fecha, en tu fecha de inicio,

Más info en [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: Esto ya lo había hecho y el resultado es que la fecha_fin entra a la tabla 0000-00-00